# MassTransit how to handle RabbitMQ going down

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

What is the proper way to configure MassTransit to be fault tolerant in order to handle intermittent RabbitMQ connectivity issues or RabbitMQ completely going down?  I've set up a RabbitMQ cluster between 2 different machines and configured HA so that everything is mirrored.  I also have an F5 load balancer set up in active/passive mode so that all traffic is directed to a primary node, but if the health check fails, it fails over to the secondary node.  I'm hoping that any client connections after such a failover will continue to succeed, but I'm running into trouble here.  When I stop RabbitMQ on the primary node, the client application starts logging a bunch of MassTransit errors that look like:

```
RabbitMQ connection failed: Connect failed: myrabbithost.mycompany.com:5671/
```

These errors occur even if no activity is happening - no Publish, Client.Request, etc.  Eventually the errors stop due to MassTransit apparently given up on the connection, and the client app crashes.  In looking at the MassTransit source, I think it's RabbitMqReceiveTransport.Receive that's generating these errors inside the "RetryUntilCancelled" method.  It looks it's using an internal ConnectionRetryPolicy, so is there something that can be configured there?

I'm instantiating my bus instance in Global.asax, starting it and keeping it around in memory as long as IIS is up, and I don't know if this is an issue or not; in looking at the documentation for MassTransit using Unity container, it looks like the recommended practice is to allow Unity to default to using the TransientLifetimeManager so that bus instances will be torn down and re-created each time the container resolves it.

Comment: Which version of MassTransit are you using?

Comment: I'm using MassTransit 3.4.1

Comment: You are right to keep the bus alive for the life of the process. It should not be transient. It should also reconnect once the broker becomes available.

Comment: And the bus keeps a temporary endpoint alive and connected to RabbitMQ. Are you sure your host name is failing over properly on the F5? We have the same setup in production and it fails over the second we drop the primary node.

Comment: Our F5 is using a health monitor that checks every 5 seconds, so maybe this is the problem?  It's looking for an HTTP 200 while accessing https://myrabbithost.mycompany.com:15671/api/.  How do you have your health monitor set up Chris?  I'm new to F5.  Can you share what you're doing for your health monitor?  By the way thanks for creating MassTransit and TopShelf - very nice working with such quality free tools!!

Comment: This post accurately describes what I'm seeing: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/masstransit-discuss/DGcjpL-iInM

Answer (score 0):

These client crashes were happening because I was using Task.Wait() like this:

```
Task.Run(() => bus.Publish(new TestMessage { Id = num })).Wait();
```

instead of this:

```
Task.Run(() => bus.Publish(new TestMessage { Id = num }));
```

Without the .Wait(), the clients stay up even when RabbitMQ goes down.  Now the issue is that any messages sent while RabbitMQ was going down but before the F5 fails over to the secondary node are lost.